# Git commit asking for comment

Tags: git

If I sometime forget to enter a comment for a git commit operation, then a screen as like follows appear to me:

[image]

However, i later on, just can't get rid of this window unless i close and open the command widow again. can anyone please help my how to handle that scenario ?

Regards

Comment: http://www.unix-manuals.com/tutorials/vi/vi-in-10-1.html - tutorial is just fine for windows too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a default editor set for Git? Try this (replace nano with your editor of choice):

`git config --global core.editor nano`

Comment: @eckes: And obviously he doesn't know how to use Vim, so he doesn't want it to be Vim.

Comment: Not obviously. I don't explore the command line much and don't have experience with Vim, so I wasn't sure (also I didn't see VIM in the title bar 'til now), Hence I suggested he set a default editor in case he hadn't yet.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you. But in the upper left corner of the window, the Vim logo is visible. Going to delete my original comment...

Answer (score 7):

You are in Vim, so just Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get into command mode.

Then if you want to save the message and commit type:
`:wq`

or if you want to abandon the commit type:
`:q!`

If you want to keep a commit, then you need to give it a message.

Answer (score 0):

It just opens an editor if you don't supply a commit message. So you'll have to close the editor before you're returned the prompt.

Since it looks like it's using VIM, you can press `ESC` then type `:wq` which saves and quits the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we're having is that git seems to enter a phase where it does not prompt for a comment.  Then something changes, and it always asks for a "merge" comment.  We can't pin down what is causing the apparent merge, because we are modifying the files in one place only.  The message is:

*Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary, especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.*

A procedure to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.