# Mercurial:cannot commit because of a strange reason

Tags: mercurial, ubuntu-14.04

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and when I type the following command in my directory:

```
hg commit hello.txt
```

I get:

```
sughosh@sughosh-desktop:~/myproject$ hg commit hello.txt
215

?

?

?

?
1




HG: Enter commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.

HG: Leave message empty to abort commit.

HG: --

HG: user: Sughosh Kaushik <sughosh.kaushik360@gmail.com>
```

So cannot enter anything and also cannot save.I have no clue what is going on.What is the fix.And what is the meaning of number which is displayed just after the command (like 336,215).

Comment: Are you perhaps facing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668191/git-commit-asking-for-comment

Comment: In any case, a screenshot would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: I have given the fpaste link.Is that helpful?The word this is hyperlinked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like because you do not specify any commit message, Mercurial is choosing one that is not working in your terminal. You can try to either:

- specify the commit message on the command line: `hg commit -m"my message" ...`
- or specify an editor of your choice before launching the commit command, e.g., if you like emacs: `export EDITOR=emacs`

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like you end up in your "favorite" editor when you commit and don't specify an explicit commit message. The "favorite" editor is usually stored in the HGEDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR environment variable - or vi if neither of those exists.

Thus possibly the editor is vi. Enter a commit message if you want. Then press escape and enter `:wq` to exit the editor.